# Creating unique url for products and categories in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, unique, primary-key, relation

I am creating a database for a website.

I am facing a problem and it is that I am not sure how to combine tables to not have the same url on a product or category.

My idea is to create 5 tables: `PRODUCTS`, `CATEGORIES`, `URLS`, `URLPRODUCTS` and `URLCATEGORIES`.

Table `PRODUCTS` has all the information of the product and an autoincrement primary key `pid`.

Same for `CATEGORIES` (`cid`).

`URLS` has got 2 columns: autoincrement primary key `uid` and unique key `url`.

The other two columns are the combination of `PRODUCTS` and `URLS` or `CATEGORIES` and `URLS`.

What structure should they have, to avoid one product to have the same url than another one or a category and to have only one url per product or category?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement seems to you have separate URL for each product and category. 
Will like to add one point that every 'product' belongs to atleast one category, so there should be a column in product for categoryId as foreign key from 'Category' tbl.
Coming to you use case:
I think there should be one more column in product & category table named 'uid' which will be foreign key from URL table, this will ensure each product/category has only one url.
Thus no need to create tbls URLPRODUCTS and URLCATEGORIES (many to many relationship case) as your req is for one to one.

Comment: And wouldn't this be problematic if I try to add the same `idurl` for a product and a category?

Comment: That would be, but will be a minor one. Also there can be a case where we need same URL for both product and category if only one product is present  in that category

Comment: Well, I do not want that. I would prefer to just show one product on that category (which will just list all products on the category, one on this case).